# C# Object Setter Not Called When Member is Modified

Tags: c#, properties, setter

I have the following wrapper class:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public int Member;
}
```

In a separate class, I have the following:

```
public class ContainerClass
{
    private Wrapper data;
    public Wrapper Property
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        Property.Member = 42;
    }
}
```

When `Property.Member` is modified in `Foo()`, nothing happens (the setter is skipped). However, I can still do the following, for example:

```
    public void Foo()
    {
        Property = Property;
    }
```

and enter the desired setter. So my question is, why doesn't modifying the member of an object property call that property's setter?

Comment: It's because you're not actually Setting the value of Property, but a member of it. To test it for example, in Foo() try doing Property = new Wrapper(){Member=42};

Comment: @Kal_Torak Ah, this explains it. However, (I hate to complicate things) in this case, I'm using this property in my ViewModel for WPF Data Binding, so if I were to use `new`, I believe I would lose my reference/binding. Suggestions?

Comment: I don't remember offhand how to handle that situation, no.  I believe Member is going to need to have a Setter/Getter though,  and the Binding will need to reference that property specifically

Comment: Oh,  and to answer your comment in the other answer,  it may be possible to call ContainerClass.PropertyChanged("Property") from inside your Wrapper class.  That'll depend on how your classes are laid out though, and on how you're implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you aren't setting the value of `Property`. Your code just invokes the getter of `Property`, then setting the value of the `Member` field (which would invoke the setter of `Member` if it were a property, which isn't the case here).

If you want to execute code when `Member` is set, you need to have

```
public class Wrapper
{
    private int member;
    public int Member
    {
        get { return this.member; }
        set 
        {
            this.member = value;
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or perhaps a more elegant solution would be to use events. The built-in [INotifyProperyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) interface gives you a pretty good template for this sort of thing.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public class Wrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int member;
    public int Member
    {
        get { return this.member; }
        set 
        {
            this.member = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Member");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
    }
}

public class ContainerClass
{
    private Wrapper data;
    public Wrapper Property
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        data.PropertyChanged += data_PropertyChanged;
        Property.Member = 42;
    }

    private void data_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Member")
        {
            DoStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you aren't modifying the reference. You are modifying the reference' member.

Say, for example, if I were to stand you in the corner of the room and say, "Hold this apple". If I come in and switch the apple with a banana.. I haven't switched you, so you're happy. But if I switch you out with someone else you'll complain that I'm replacing you.

..that is my analogy for this anyway.

Also, you've prefixed a class with `I`.. this is generally used on interfaces in .NET land..

EDIT: I realise that if I were to stand you in a corner holding a piece of fruit.. you probably wouldn't complain when I replaced you..

Comment: I would have used a pineapple

Comment: I know, it was all I could think of in a pinch... I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of foo, you are setting the field of class Wrapper.

```
public void Foo()
{
    Property.Member = 42; // No property set, you are accessing a field.
}
```

In the second example, you are setting a property

```
public void Foo()
{
    // Setting Property "Property" to the value of "Property"
    // You should see both the getter and the setter called.
    Property = Property; 
}
```

I do not know what you are attempting to do, but maybe you wanted Wrapper to have a property too.

```
public class Wrapper
{
private int member;
public int Member
{
    get { return data; }
    set { data = value; }
}
}
```

Then the setter would be called on Wrapper.Member when you did Property.Member = 42

Comment: Right. `Wrapper.Member` is actually a property in my code, but it wasn't directly related to my question, so I cut it, for clarity. Ideally, I would like both setters (`Property` and `Property.Member`) to be called. But that may not be possible in this case.

Comment: You are correct, that is not auto-magically possible. Please vote up my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Usually people add an object to a list directly by Add() method which, in turn, does not trigger the setter.

```
private List<string> _namesList = new List<string>();
// list of names
public List<string> NamesList
{    
    get
    {
    return _namesList;
    }
    set
    {
    if (value == _namesList)
    {
    return;
    }
    _namesList = value;
    }
}
```

In above NamesList property, if you call NamesList.Add("test") it won't invoke setter. Simple solution is store the list in a new variable and gradually set that variable to NamesList e.g.

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>{ "test1" };
d.NamesList = lst;              // setter will fire.
```

But it's a common mistake to add an object to a list/collection directly. :)